# Finding a formula for the number of links for a series of n delete-min operations in a Trinary Heap

Tags: data-structures

**Question**
We have an empty trinary heap.
Given n (say 10000) operations of insert, and then 10000 of delete-min. What is the number of linking operations we will have.

**Thoughts**
After programming this heap in Java, the number of links occured was 9992 for inserts and the rest for deletes (the total number of links was 138266. I think I may have proved that building a trianry heap with insert costs O(n) which is good. I don't really know how to build a formula to EXPLAIN the remaining links.
Would love help with that. A linking operation is defined as linking two trees together (making one of them a father to the other).

Comment: Is a trinary heap a generalization of a binary heap (that is, a heap-ordered, complete ternary tree) or a binomial heap (that is, a collection of heap-ordered trinomial trees)?

Comment: generalization of bin heap

Comment: Sorry, is that **bin**-ary or **bin**-omial heap?